# Is it possible to add a variable into a jquery select function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i want to select the div with a Class that have same name as my $id variable.

Everything is working if i add the div id by myself but i want it to be based on my $id variable.

Is this possible or is there a better way to target the right div based on the button that was clicked?

```
$('.checkbox-group').find('input[value=button]').click(function() { //find all buttons with value=button

var $toggle = $(this); 
//add buttons in variable $toggle

var $id = $( this ).attr('id');                                     
//add the clicked button´s ID in the variable $id

if ($toggle.prop('checked') === true) {                             
//if the clicked button is checked 

$('#my-grp div.$id').removeClass('kill');                       
//want to select the div with Class that have same name as my $id variable

} else {
//and then add or remove the class .kill

$('#my-grp div.$id').addClass('kill');                          
}
});
```

Comment: Include some sample HTML so we can see what your code is trying to do.

Comment: This is JavaScript not PHP. You don't need `$` before your var and it doesn't see your variable in the string. You need to concatenate, like in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just a simple string concatenation away :)

```
$('#my-grp div.' + $id).removeClass('kill');
```

Comment: thank you for a fast and simple answer :D

Answer (score 0):

jQuery won't process variables in string quotes, you should concatenate it.

Instead of this:

```
$('#my-grp div.$id').removeClass('kill');
```

write this:

```
$('#my-grp div.' + $id).removeClass('kill');
```

*EDIT: Oops, it looks someone was faster :)*

Answer (score 0):

You can concat string and variables. In your case something like this:

```
$('#my-grp div.' + $id ).removeClass('kill');
```

Side note:
Variables in javascript doesn't need a `$`. In you case `id` would be a better variable name to store a string.

`$` is normally used to store jquery elements, like `$toggle`.